# Finding distribution function of the ratio of two continuous uniform random variables where the denominator random variable is squared.

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ be independent and uniformly distributed
between 0 and 1.

I want to find the distribution function of $X_{3}=\dfrac{X_{2}}{X_{1}^{2}}$.
Denote this distibution

function by $F(z)$. I know that this function is piecewise with three
domain

intervals: $z<0,\;0\leq z\leq1,\; z>1$. How do I find the upper limit
of the

second interval (i.e. 1 in $0\leq z\leq1$)? Also what is the reasoning
behind finding

the functions in the last two intervals?

Answer (score 1):

A picture can help:

[image]

\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{X_3}(z) &=& P(X_2/X_1^2 \leq z) \\
&=& P(X_2 \leq zX_1^2).
\end{eqnarray*}

It should be obvious that $F_{X_3}(z)=0$ if $z\lt 0$. For $0\lt z\lt 1$, the first picture applies and for $z\gt 1$ the second picture applies. In both cases, because $X_1,X_2$ are uniform and independent, we need the area under the curve $x_2 = zx_1^2$.

For $0\lt z\lt 1$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X_2 \leq zX_1^2) &=& \int_0^1 zx_1^2\;dx_1 \\
&=& \left[\frac{zx_1^3}{3} \right]_0^1 \\
&=& \frac{z}{3}.
\end{eqnarray*}

For $z\gt 1$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X_2 \leq zX_1^2) &=& \int_0^{1/\sqrt{z}} zx_1^2\;dx_1 + \int_{1/\sqrt{z}}^1 1\;dx_1 \\
&=& \left[\frac{zx_1^3}{3} \right]_0^{1/\sqrt{z}} + \left[x_1 \right]_{1/\sqrt{z}}^1 \\
&=&1 - \dfrac{2}{3\sqrt{z}}.
\end{eqnarray*}