# Find the density function of $U=X/Y$

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independently uniformly distributed with densities.
$f(x) = 1$, $0 < x < 1$ and $f(y) = 1$, $0 < y < 1$. Let $U = {X\over
Y}$. Find the density function of $U$.

Would you explain the way of solving these kind of questions? There are different versions like $U=X+Y$ or $U=XY$ as well.

Comment: Please include your thoughts and efforts in this and future posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: see here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291604/finding-distribution-function-of-the-ratio-of-two-continuous-uniform-random-vari

Answer (score 0):

The probability is best worked with in cumulative distribution.  You want to determine for what places in xy-space you get $U=X/Y<z$ for a given z.  The xy-space is the unit square, and depending on what z is, you need to look at the 2 different cases, $z<1$ and $z>1$, depending on which boundary the line $y=\frac{1}{z} x$ hits.

When $z<1$ you get for the cumulative distribution
$$P(U<z)=P(x<zy)=\int_0^{1} \int_{0}^{zy}dxdy=\frac{z}{2}$$
When $z>1$ you get
$$P(U<z)=P(x<zy)=\int_0^{1} \int_{x/z}^{1}dydx=1-\frac{1}{2z}$$
The distribution you want is then the derivative, so for $z<1$ you get $$P=1/2,$$ and for $z>1$ you get $$P=\frac{1}{2z^2}$$