# Find the Density of U = X / Y

Tags: probability, statistics

My question is more of an extension of this previous question asked and a couple more doubts on top of the post's answer myself

[Find the density function of $U=X/Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604764/find-the-density-function-of-u-x-y)

I understand that $ y = x/u $, I drew out the picture and found that I got $  \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x/u}1 \,dydx$ instead, which obviously is wrong.

What I understand is that I have to first draw a square, and then sketch the graph of $y=x/u$ to determine the ranges of which to integrate from.

I don't understand from that post, when does one flip the order in which to integrate? And afterwards, how does he decide on the range to integrate to with respect to y or x?

Also, why does one need to consider cases where $u < 1$ and $u >= 1$ ? Won't both cases result in a range of $y$ that is from $0$ to $x/u$ because $y = x/u$?

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $U \leq u$ is the area of the region $\{ y \geq x/u \}$ intersected with $[0,1]^2$. When $u > 1$, this region is a trapezium, since the line $y = x/u$ intersects the boundary of $[0,1]^2$ on the `left hand side' of the box, whereas when $u < 1$, this region is a triangle, since $y = x/u$ leaves the box from its top side.

Because these regions are differently shaped it is reasonable to consider these cases separately and swap the order of integration.

In the case $u \geq 1$ you do not have a range of $y$ that is from $0$ to $x/u$ because you might have $x/u \geq 1$ and $y$ cannot take values greater than 1. However, it is true that you will get a range of $y$ that is from $0$ to $\text{min}(1,x/u)$.